# Trying to compile C with Sublime Text 2 but can't input anything with scanf

Tags: c, build, sublimetext2, scanf

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (void)
{
    int a;
    scanf("%d",&a);
    printf("Hi %d\n",a);
    return 0;
}
```

> ```
> make: `untitled' is up to date.
> Hi 1715736630
> [Finished in 0.0s]
> ```

I know I can build in ST2 and then double click the result on desktop. But maybe there is a way to launch terminal from ST2 so I can input a variable after pressing Shift+Cmd+B? Because this console at the bottom won't let me write in it. Thanks.

Comment: SublimeText2 is not a compiler (perhaps an editor or an IDE). You should configure your system to compile with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` then use the `gdb` debugger; I would suggest to compile and debug in a terminal on the command line

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you are using Mac. I don't know much about Mac but, in Windows with MinGW, you may use a very complex kludge creating a batch file if you don't mind creating a garbage batch file. Just add a new build system by selecting "`Tools` -> `Build System` -> `New Build System...`" and enter the following script:

```
{
    "windows":
    {
        "cmd": ["g++","${file}","-o","${file_base_name}","&&",
                "echo","@echo","off",">","_${file_base_name}.bat","&&",
                "echo","${file_base_name}.exe","^&","pause",">>","_${file_base_name}.bat","&&",
                "echo","exit",">>","_${file_base_name}.bat","&&",
                "start","_${file_base_name}.bat"]
    },
    "shell": true,
    "working_dir": "${file_path}",
    "selector": "source.c, source.c++"
}
```

Save the above using Ctrl+S as a new name say "`MyC++.sublime-build`" and select the new build system using "`Tools` -> `Build System`". Now Ctrl+B will open a new command prompt for user interaction. It's dirty a little bit but works (I'm using ST2).

I hope the similar technique may be devised in Mac or Linux in general.